# Removing Specific Lines from a Richtextbox in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, richtextbox

I have a `checkboxlist` where the user chooses which kind of lines he will have removed from a `richtextbox` with a text printout. For example, a header of a printout, with company name, date, etc.

These unwanted lines change from every other text file, that's why the user needs to choose via a `checkbox` which lines are going to be deleted.

For example, the string `PAGE 1 OF 12` repeats on every page, but, of course, the page changes. So there's a substring to get just the start of the sequence, so it can remove all of the lines that start with `PAGE`. The printed date starts with the word `DATE`, and should also be removed.

But this is not the important part.
The important part is that the amount of lines to be eliminated changes for every file. Sometimes it won't have a company name; sometimes it will.
I did a `FOR` loop, going through each of the checked lines to be deleted, and deleting each and every one from the `richtextbox`. Then got back to the beginning and repeated the process `FOREACH` checked item.
It takes a very long time.

So I came out with this solution, using two `textBox` for this example:

```
string searchKeyword = textBox1.Text;
string searchKeyword2 = textBox2.Text;

var lines = richTextBox1.Lines;
foreach (string line in lines.Where(l => (!l.StartsWith(searchKeyword)) && (!l.StartsWith(searchKeyword2))))
    _items.Add(line);
listBox2.DataSource = null;
listBox2.DataSource = _items;
```

This is much faster. But how to do the search dynamically, using each of checked items in 'checklistbox' so I can come out with a clean output?

**My question is:** how can I replace the lambda string for a variable amount of `searchkeywords`?

This is the kind of code that works, but it takes a very long time:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
List<string> substrings = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    substrings.Add(item.ToString().Substring(0, 4));
}
```

At the end, what I need is to get the chosen lines from a `richtextbox` and eliminate those lines, in a clever way.